# How to loop SVG animation sequence?

Tags: animation, svg, smil

I have sequence of `animationTransform`:

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0" to="30" begin="0s" dur="0.4s" fill="freeze"/>
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="30" to="0" begin="0.4s" dur="0.4s" fill="freeze"/>
```

If it possible to loop this sequence without using script?

I can set individual animation to loop by using `repeatCount="indefinite"` by I want to loop the whole sequence in order.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Figured it out already. Solution for those who are interested:

```
<animateTransform id="anim1" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0" to="30" begin="0s; anim2.end" dur="0.4s" fill="freeze"/>
<animateTransform id="anim2" attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="30" to="0" begin="anim1.end" dur="0.4s" fill="freeze"/>
```

Comment: Works in (oold) Firefox 10, doesn't work in (up-to-date) Chrome 32, just if anyone encounters the same issue. And some useful links describing all the capabilities of animation timing: [W3C SVG 1.1 Spec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#TimingAttributes), [Developer.Mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin).

Answer (score 36):

You can also just loop within a single `animateTransform` by providing a `values` attribute with a semi-colon separated list:

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate"
     values="0;30;0" begin="0s" dur="0.8s" fill="freeze"
     repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

[Here's an example](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/animate-loop.svg) (checked in Firefox 4.0 and Chrome).

Comment: @janaspage I just stumbled across documentation for the values attribute here: http://www.w3.org/TR/smil-animation/#ValuesAttribute

Comment: although this accomplishes the task, it doesn't actually sequence two animations; would be nice to know how to sequence animations and repeart them in SMIL

Answer (score 8):

it's also possible to add/subtract (milli)seconds:

```
  begin="anim2.end-500ms"
```