# How to create an endless animation loop in SVG

Tags: svg, rotation, angle

I'm new to SVG-Animation and I tried to rotate a group-element eight times by 45°. (45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315, 360).
Example below works fine for me, but how do I create an endless loop of the entire animation? Now it only runs once.

I'm open minded for other possibilities...

Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">  
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="128px" height="128px" viewBox="0 0 16 16">

    <g>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="45 8 8" begin="1000ms"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="90 8 8" begin="2000ms"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="135 8 8" begin="3000ms"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="180 8 8" begin="4000ms"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="225 8 8" begin="5000ms"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="270 8 8" begin="6000ms"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="315 8 8" begin="7000ms"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="360 8 8" begin="8000ms"/>

        <rect fill="#404040" x="7.062" y="3.625" width="1.875" height="8.75"/>
    </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to loop SVG animation sequence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629987/how-to-loop-svg-animation-sequence)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change your example to use only one animateTransform element with all angles provided in the `values` attribute, you can use the `repeatCount` attribute to set the number of times the animation should be repeated. If the repeatCount is set to indefinite, the animation will repeat forever.

The following example I think will do what you are looking for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">  
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="128px" height="128px" viewBox="0 0 16 16">

    <g>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" 
           values="0 8 8; 45 8 8; 90 8 8; 135 8 8; 180 8 8; 225 8 8; 270 8 8; 315 8 8" 
           dur="8s" calcMode="discrete" repeatCount="indefinite" />

        <rect fill="#404040" x="7.062" y="3.625" width="1.875" height="8.75"/>
    </g>


</svg>
```