# The ‘set’ element - loop

Tags: svg, smil

I have:

```
<set attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="visible" begin="5s" fill="freeze"/>
<set attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="hidden" begin="10s" fill="freeze"/>
```

I want the loop to perform these instructions.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "the loop"? Are you saying that you want to use SMIL animation to repeatedly show and hide an item every 5 seconds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to loop SVG animation sequence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629987/how-to-loop-svg-animation-sequence)

Answer (score 5):

If you want the item to continuously "blink" on and off, you need to set the animations to have a duration and begin when the other ends. For example:

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rnSFY/

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle fill="red" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30" stroke="black">
    <set id="show" attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="visible"
         begin="0s; hide.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>
    <set id="hide" attributeName="visibility" attributeType="CSS" to="hidden"
         begin="show.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>
  </circle>
</svg>​
```

Comment: Phrogz, why not a simple animate?

Comment: @KyleMit I don't know; it's hard to remember what I was thinking 2.5 years ago. If you feel that you have an alternative and good solution, I suggest that you ought to post an answer. Oh wait, you did! +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

Rather than toggling back and forth between two different static [`set`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-smil-animation-20010904/#setElement) elements, you can use a single [`animate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-smil-animation-20010904/#animateElement) that switch between hidden and visible indefinitely.

Then you also don't need to worry about wiring up the begin timing with the end event of another named animation

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle fill="red" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30" stroke="black">
    <animate attributeType="CSS"
             attributeName="visibility"
             from="visible" 
             to="hidden"
             dur="1s"
             repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle>
</svg>
```